# Applying regex in Spring Cloud Gateway Path predicate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm using 3.1.0 version for Spring Cloud Gateway and I need help in checking and fixing the Path predicate filter for my route configuration.

I'm trying to use regex in between a path, the route looks something like this in my config:

```
        - id: Route1
          uri: https://example.com
          predicates:
            - Path=/random/path/\d+/update
            - Method=POST
```

Though this is a valid regex, I'm getting **404 error code** for requests for path :

> /random/path/12/update

Hence I need help to figure out the correct configs for this usecase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It requires a named path segment. See the syntax [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/pattern/PathPattern.html). You can then use `{mynum}` in filters like `SetPath`

```
    - id: Route1
      uri: https://example.com
      predicates:
        - Path=/random/path/{mynum:\d+}/update
        - Method=POST
```

Comment: Thankyou, I understand it uses java PathMatcher for Path prefix. Also, shouldn't it be \\d+ then?

Comment: No, this isn't a java string, it's yaml. Escaping the slash is only required in java strings. See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/commit/2befc5804c4cc48fd0156c722aac1971b9b5c55b#diff-48667f9193ed1e38042be10d6903ff856fdff31ea11d6222c52082d0fcc8ad6dR270

Comment: Got it. Thanks!